# Precompiling svg images in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use svg images in my rails application, they are located in /app/assets/images. I also added svg for precompilation (config/application.rb):

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg )
```

However, using that on production, it results in an exception:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (image.svg isn't precompiled):
```

what do I need to add to precompile the svg and make it accessable?

Answer (score 2):

This was a problem with my capistrano script. I introduced a namespace called `rake` but also had a variable `rake` that defined the command line for executing rake. Namespace overwrote that variable and the precompile task wasn't called correctly.

After I fixed that, it's working just fine.